# ¿Cómo obtener todos los usuarios de un pais usando la api de stackoverflow?

Tags: api

Estoy queriendo obtener todos los usuarios de un determinado país usando la api de StackOverFlow. Estoy buscando la forma y no encuentro. La única forma que encontré era usando **https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?page=99&pagesize=99&order=desc&sort=reputation&site=es.stackoverflow** pero me trae paginado de todos los usuarios. Yo quisiera que solo me traiga de un determinado país.

```
function cargar(){
    var parametros = {
        "order": "desc",
        "sort": "reputation",
        //"page": 208,
        "pagesize": 100,
        "site": "es.stackoverflow"
     };

    $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url:  'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users',
        type:  'get',
        success: function (resultado) {
            var array = Array();
            var items = resultado.items;
            var indice_location;

            for(var indice in items){
                var location = items[indice].location;
                if(location){
                    indice_location = array.indexOf(location);

                    if(indice_location == -1){
                        array.push(location);
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log("Resultado: ", array);
            console.log("resultado: ", resultado);
        }
    });
}
```

Me trae de todos los usuarios. Yo quisiera saber si puedo mandar un parámetro o llamar a otro método para traer de un país especifico.

Comment: Puedes poner más código? Dónde quieres tratar el resultado?

Comment: @sakulino ahí agregue.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas en la función podrías poner `location`, sino trata el json después de recibir la petición...

```
function cargar(){
    var parametros = {
        "order": "desc",
        "sort": "reputation",
        "location" : "Spain",
        //"page": 208,
        "pagesize": 100,
        "site": "es.stackoverflow"
     };

$.ajax({
    data: parametros,
    url:  'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users',
    type:  'get',
    success: function (resultado) {
        var array = Array();
        var items = resultado.items;
        var indice_location;
        var location = "Spain";
        for(var indice in items){
                if(location==indice.location){
                     array.push(indice);
                }
            }
            console.log("Resultado: ", array);
            console.log("resultado: ", resultado);
        }
    });
}
```